# Efficient NSArray and float * conversion

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsarray

I know it's possible to convert between `float *` and NSArray (or NSMutableArray) with

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) x[i] = [[array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

for (int i=0; i<N; i++) [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x[i]]];
```

But those both use for-loops which are slow and inefficient. I'd like to see `x = [array toFloatArray]`. Almost anything that uses images/anything iOS related and requires lower level libraries (BLAS, LAPACK, etc) requires this conversion, and it would be nice to speed it up.

Comment: So you think `x = [array toFloatArray]` won't iterate over the array?  Seems like you want to save typing more than anything.

Comment: I know there's gains from vectorized code (e.g. BLAS) and I'm guessing a function like that would also be vectorized.

Comment: Isn't "vectorized code" a compiler optimisation?  If so that won't help with arbitrary arrays, only coded `for` loops etc.

Comment: If it's a compiler optimization, why do libraries such as BLAS and LAPACK exist? That's what I'm trying to emulate.

Comment: I don't know anything about them.  I think the best you'll get is *fast enumeration*.

Comment: Your BLAS can be carefully written by a human who will do a much better job than a compiler will.  The speed difference between compiler-vectorised BLAS and human-written BLAS can be surprisingly large.

Comment: Note, however, that loops are not "slow and inefficient" in objective C.  I don't know anything about ios programming, but any overhead would have to come from the addObject call or by wrapping with NSNumber.)

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, or which library is involved, to get floats from NSNumbers which are in an NSArray, there is no way to get around code which is more or less like what you've already shown.

If you want speed, use raw C-arrays and manage them yourself.

If the code you are using provides or requires NSArrays with NSNumbers containing floats, instead of raw C-arrays, there is nothing you can do.